# Why doesn’t my service worker store all the items during the “installation” event?

Tags: javascript, caching, dom-events, service-worker, browser-cache

This is the code for my service worker for the “installation” event:

```
const CACHE_NAME = "static3";

self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
   event.waitUntil(
      caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function (cache) {
         cache.addAll([
            "/",
            "/blog/",
            "/links/",
            "/about/",
            "/contact/",
            "/privacyPolicy/",
            "/offline/",
            "/css/CP.ttf",
            "/css/CPItalic.ttf",
            "/css/WS.ttf",
            "/css/WSItalic.tff",
            "/css/style.css",
            "/css/typography.css"
         ]);
      })
   );
});
```

I tried several times but the service worker doesn’t store all the items in the cache. This is a screenshot from Google Chrome’s “Application” tab:

[image]

Why are only some items stored in the cache? Keep in mind that all the paths to the other files are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. As you can see, I accidentally wrote `"/css/WSItalic.tff"` instead of `"/css/WSItalic.ttf"`. This caused the “install” event to reject all of the items, since it stores them unless there’s even a single error in the paths. So, the “install” event rejected the files to store in the cache and only the fetch requests from the page I was viewing were stored.